# $S=\{1,2,3...,100\}$ and $a,b,c$ belong to $S$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 5c+3$. Find number of ordered $(a,b,c)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S=\{1,2,3...,100\}$ and let $a,b,c$ belong to $S$ such that $a² + b² = 5c+3$
Find number of ordered $(a,b,c)$.

My approach to this was that $a²$ can only be $0,1,4 \pmod 5$
So since, $a²+b²=3 \pmod 5$, clearly $b²=4 \pmod 5$. However, after this I just can't proceed. I would appreciate a full solution.

Comment: You are most of the way there. You need $a^2\equiv b^2\equiv4\pmod5$. What does that tell you about $a$? about $b$? How many such $a,b$ are there?

Comment: You've gathered that both $a^2$ and $b^2$ are $4 \pmod 5$. Next, note that $a$ and $b$ can be $2,3 \pmod 5$. How many integers of this form exist in $S$? Are $a$ and $b$ dependent on each other? Hence, can you find the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+b^2 \le 503$? Also, can you show that for each pair $(a,b)$, a unique $c$ exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have identified, $a^2$ and $b^2$ must both be $4\pmod5$, which means $a$ and $b$ can either be $2$ or $3\pmod5$. Since $1\le c\le100$, $5c+3\le503$, so the maximum value $a$ and $b$ can take is $22$. Since the numbers are quite small, we can work this out case-by-case.

[image]
Therefore, the total number of ordered pairs is $9+9+8+8+8+8+6+6+2=64$ ordered $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: I'm curious, how long might it have taken you to come up with the entire answer?

Comment: 5-10 minutes? You were really only one step away from finishing the problem yourself anyway.